# How to get list of wallets generated by PAB

Tags: plutus-pab

I'd like to know what endpoint to call to get the list of wallets generated by PAB during initialization (after calling `cabal run myapp` and seen after ending PAB - by pressing enter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, there is no such endpoint call.

What you can get is all contract instances:

- By wallet: `/api/contract/instances/wallet/<wallet-id>`
- Or general: `/api/contract/instances`

Check here all PAB endpoints:
[PAB API endpoints](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/744d3fd0b9132f7871f8515b975ac112d3019d9c/plutus-pab/src/Plutus/PAB/Webserver/API.hs#L36-L49)