# How to get the final balances using the PAB+ the simulator?

Tags: plutus, wallet, pab, simulator

I'm using the GuessGame:

https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/a36af17fd38db591865679916c819079ad51fda2/plutus-playground-server/usecases/Game.hs

under the simulator, with this code

```
main = Simulator.runSimulationWith handlers $ do

     cid <- Simulator.activateContract (Wallet 1) GuessGame

     waitNSlots 3
     callEndpointOnInstance cid "lock" LockParams{secretWord="world", amount= Ada.adaValueOf 200}

     waitNSlots 3
     callEndpointOnInstance cid "guess" GuessParams{guessWord="world"}
  
  where
  handlers :: SimulatorEffectHandlers (Builtin TestContracts)
  handlers =
    Simulator.mkSimulatorHandlers def def
    $ interpret (contractHandler (Builtin.handleBuiltin @TestContracts))
```

The traces included in the GuessGame code, indicates that the transaction has been done, but how I can display the final balances of the the simulated accounts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get list of wallets generated by PAB](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4221/how-to-get-list-of-wallets-generated-by-pab)

Answer (score 1):

You need to include these lines at the end:

```
Simulator.logString @(Builtin TestContracts) "Balances at the end of the simulation"
b <- Simulator.currentBalances
Simulator.logBalances @(Builtin TestContracts) b
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works!

Comment: @agocorona Glad to help!